# How to apply Dark Mode to p-card with a toggle button?

Tags: angular, primeng, togglebutton, darkmode

I am an Angular beginner. Currently, I have a task to apply Dark Mode to an angular app.
The body background color is successfully switching as expected (using angular-dark-mode npm - See Details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-dark-mode)

In the npm doc, I think I can only apply the dark theme to global styles (i.e. body).

I tried the following in style.css already - but cannot see any style changes:

```
.p-card.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
}

.p-card.light-mode {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Here is my code:

**[dark-mode.component.html]**

```
<p-toggleButton
  [(ngModel)]="checked"
  onLabel="Dark_Mode"
  offLabel="Light_Mode"
  (onChange)="onToggle()"
  styleClass="darkMode_btn"
></p-toggleButton>
```

**[dark-mode.component.ts]**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DarkModeService } from 'angular-dark-mode';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dark-mode',
  templateUrl: './dark-mode.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dark-mode.component.scss'],
})
export class DarkModeComponent {
  darkMode$ = this.darkModeService.darkMode$;
  checked: boolean = true;

  constructor(private darkModeService: DarkModeService) {}

  onToggle(): void {
    this.darkModeService.toggle();
  }
}
```

**[style.css]**

```
body.dark-mode {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #2d3436;
  color: #dfe6e9;
}

body.light-mode {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  color: #2d3436;
}

.darkMode_btn {
  height: 45px;
}

.p-card.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
}

.p-card.light-mode {
  background-color: white;
}
```

So my question is simple. How can I apply the dark mode to  in angular with a toggle button?
Any idea, please?

------- Edited -------------------

I forgot to add one more thing. Here is how the structure of .HTML having the  tags looks like:

```
<main>
    <p-card styleClass="toolCard">
        ....
    </p-card>
</main>
```

And I was able to see how other styles apply to the tag:

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep .toolCard.p-card {
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin: 1em 0em;
    background-color: var(--bluegray-50);
    .p-card-body {
      padding: 0.5rem;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding .dark-mode to the end of the .p-card-body. However, it did not make any difference.
Still not working.. any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have nearly everything set up correctly. However, `angular-dark-mode` only adds the `light-mode` and `dark-mode` classes to the body tag. It does not add the class to other tags.

Try setting the following in your style.css:

```
body.dark-mode p-card {
  background-color: black;
}

body.light-mode p-card {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Still not working...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

[style.css]

```
body.dark-mode .toolCard.p-card {
  .p-card-body {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

body.light-mode .toolCard.p-card {
  .p-card-body {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```